# Why does Range().AdvancedFilter for unique values ignore the first row?

Tags: excel, vba

TLDR: Why does the sorting algorithm ignore (in regards of uniqueness) and just copy the first value?

The following code

```
Sub test()

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A7").AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("B1"), _
    Unique:=True

End Sub
```

filters the following rows:

```
A1 to A7:
1
1
2
3
4
1
2
```

to:

```
1
1
2
3
4
```

I tried it with text, different starting rows, sorting in place instead of copying to another range, but it seems as if the first value is just copied and not compared with anything in regards to being unique.

[Range.AdvancedFilter method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841242.aspx) does not mention anything.

The result should be that the Range A1:A7 is uniquely filtered (sort order is not important):

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: What is the result you want to get ?

Comment: @ Shai: updated question

Comment: It's because it's assuming the first row is the header row and just copies it. Try replacing it with 2 or 3, and it will copy it as weel

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that as well. But I found no documentary mentioning anything of that behavior, and I don't know how to fix it. I could always just leave one cell blank above my list, but that seems like an ugly fix to me.

Comment: You can use the more complex way with a `Dictionary`

Comment: @ShaiRado if you remove the header (Range("A2:A7").AdvancedFilter) you still get a duplicate 1. I gave up on autofilter a long time ago in favour of a udf

Comment: @DavidG - behaviour confirmed, this is normal and IMO a bug that was never fixed. Can you use VBA?

Comment: This, or just sort it by hand with an array. But it seems odd to me that this behavior is not documented at all, and I am pretty sure that I'm not the first one to recognize this, so I wonder why I did not find anything regarding this topic

Comment: @Absinthe thanks. tested it now, and you're right

Comment: You can just copy the entire Column A to Column B, and use `RemoveDuplicates` on Column B

Comment: @Absinthe Yes, I can handle it in other ways, this question was just out of curiosity

Comment: It is *not* a bug. All filter methods require a header row, both in code and in the Excel UI.

Comment: @Rory Thank you for the clarificaion. Are you aware of any official documentation on this?

Comment: Not off the top of my head but it's fairly self-evident for advanced filter given that the criteria range headers have to match the data range headers (unless using a formula).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question directly, as I just spent time debugging this myself. **You MUST have a "Header" row in your range that is being filtered.** *This is not considered a bug, but a requirement of* `AdvancedFilter`.

I have no sources for this other than this page, but I can confirm OP's results and comments make sense and support this answer. If anybody has official links/docs regarding this matter please share!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `RemoveDuplicates` on Column B:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A7").Copy ActiveSheet.Range("B1")
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Of course, there's no need to use `ActiveSheet`, and it's better to use fully qualified `Worksheets` instead:

```
With Worksheets("YourSheetName")
    .Range("A1:A7").Copy .Range("B1")
    .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End With
```

Comment: I almost NEVER use a fully qualified worksheet, causes more issues then using ActiveSheet in my use case scenario. Everyone always acts like fully qualified must be better, but it isn't always.

Comment: As @DavidG commented, he knows how to do it other ways, this doesn't answer the OP's question.